# Bind storyboard color animation from local string variable

Tags: wpf, binding, storyboard, coloranimation

I'm still a bit of an amateur in regards to binding in WPF but I was hoping I could get some help in regards to binding a string to a storyboard animation. I have a custom UserControl with nothing more then a TextBox and some buttons laid out. What I want to do is whenever the TextBox gets information from the server that the foreground would animate from a light color to a dark color. Upon creation of this control the user specifies what colors they want to see animated. As an example let's go with light green to dark green. I have 2 variables inside the UserControl that are stored as strings and now I would like to bind them to the storyboard animation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

XAML:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.TextChanged">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="False" Duration="0:0:2" From="{Binding StartTextColor}" To="{Binding EndTextColor}"
                Storyboard.TargetName="txtTextField" AccelerationRatio="1" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                 FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
            </ColorAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Code:

```
public string StartTextColor
{
    get
    {
        return startTextColor;
    }
    set
    {
        startTextColor= value;
    }
}

public string EndTextColor
{
    get
    {
        return _endTextColor;
    }
    set
    {
        _endTextColor= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the properties have to be strings? or can you just use `Color?`

Comment: Are you sure you are using proper names for the colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just done a quick test with `string` color binding to your animation and it works fine.
If you're ever binding you should make sure your object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` as this notifies the XAML that a property has changed.

My Test:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string startTextColor = "Green";
        private string _endTextColor = "Red";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string StartTextColor
        {
            get { return startTextColor; }
            set
            {
                startTextColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("StartTextColor");
            }
        }

        public string EndTextColor
        {
            get { return _endTextColor; }
            set
            {
                _endTextColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("EndTextColor");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies the property changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info">The info.</param>
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="2640" Name="UI" >
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Name="txtbx">
              <TextBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.TextChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="False" Duration="0:0:2" AccelerationRatio="1" Storyboard.TargetName="txtbx" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" 
                                            From="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=StartTextColor}" 
                                            To="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=EndTextColor}"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            </ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
              </TextBox.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you just explain to me why you're passing in 'UI' as the element name?

Comment: I got it all setup now. I had to set the data context to self.